# How to translate COUNTIFS formula in ARRAYFORMULA to automatically insert the formula in each row

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

With my `countifs` formula in column C I want to auto-number (running total) all occurrences of an identical string in column A (e.g. Apple or Orange) but only if on the same row where the string appears column B is of a certain type, e.g. if in column B the type is of "fruit" in column C auto number all occurrences of an identical string in column A. For each new string which is of type "fruit" start the numbering all over again.

The outcome should be like this:

```
+---+-----------+-------+---+--+
|   |     A     |   B   | C |  |
+---+-----------+-------+---+--+
| 1 | Apple     | Fruit | 1 |  |
| 2 | Apple     | Fruit | 2 |  |
| 3 | Mercedes  | Car   | 0 |  |
| 4 | Mercedes  | Car   | 0 |  |
| 5 | Orange    | Fruit | 1 |  |
| 6 | Orange    | Fruit | 2 |  |
| 7 | Apple     | Fruit | 3 |  |
+---+-----------+-------+---+--+
```

The formula in column C:

```
=COUNTIFS($A1:$A$1;A1;$B1:$B$1;"Fruit")
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A2;A2;$B$1:$B2;"Fruit")
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A3;A3;$A$1:$A3;"Fruit")
…and so on…
```

I want to translate this formula into an array formula and put this into the header so the formula will automatically expand.

No matter what I've tried it won't work.

Any help is truly appreciated!

Here's a link to a sheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lgbuLbTSnyKkqr33NdVuDEv5eoXFwatX1rgeF9YpIks/edit?usp=sharing][1]

Answer (score 1):

```
={"ARRAYFORMULA HERE"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), IF(B2:B="Fruit",
 MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B))), N(B2:B="Fruit"))-
 HLOOKUP(0, MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B))), N(B2:B="Fruit")),
 MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B), IF(N(B2:B<>B1:B), ROW(B2:B), ), 1, 1),
       VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B), IF(N(B2:B<>B1:B), ROW(B2:B), ), 1, 1), 0), 0), 0), ))}
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

[**demo spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nFaJK5MUxn5yT1QT1qgH1JEEtN-nyCp1u6mTzIdlFKk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This gives me an error. Could you please explain a bit what you're doing with this formula? Thanks

Comment: this fx does exactly what you request. see the updated answer with demo sheet and notice the 2nd picture

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but when I insert the fx into my sheet the fx will continuously count all strings of type fruit no matter what the string is. The fx doesn't differentiate between Orange or Apple. Only when I insert a string which is NOT of type fruit and right after that insert a string of type fruit again the counter will start all over again. You can see that here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lgbuLbTSnyKkqr33NdVuDEv5eoXFwatX1rgeF9YpIks/edit?usp=sharing (Sheet 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), IF(B2:B="Fruit",
 MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B))), N(B2:B="Fruit")), 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This formula works not as expected. It now auto numbers all strings of type fruit continuously. Let's say I have 2 rows with "Apple" and "Fruit" but also 2 rows with "Orange" and "Fruit". The apple/fruit combo should count up to 2 (1,2) and the orange/fruit combo should start all over again (1,2). I've updated my post so it's clearer.